# When does the move constructor get called rather than the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I read a Microsoft tutorial (located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/move-constructors-and-move-assignment-operators-cpp?view=msvc-170) about the move constructor and the move assignment operator and I didn't quite understand when the move ctor is invoked.

Below the code of the MemoryBlock class

```
class MemoryBlock
{
public:
    explicit MemoryBlock(size_t length)
        : m_length(length),
          m_data(new int[length])
    {
        std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(size_t). length = "
                  << m_length << "." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~MemoryBlock()
    {
        std::cout << "In ~MemoryBlock(). length = "
                  << m_length << ".";

        if (m_data != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] m_data;
            m_data = nullptr;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Copy ctor
    MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock& other)
        : m_length(other.m_length),
          m_data(new int[other.m_length])
    {
        std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock&). length = "
                        << other.m_length << ". Copying resource." << std::endl;

        std::copy(other.m_data, other.m_data + m_length, m_data);
    }

    // Copy assignment operator
    MemoryBlock& operator=(const MemoryBlock& other)
    {
        std::cout << "In operator=(const MemoryBlock&). length = "
                        << other.m_length << ". Copying resource." << std::endl;

        if (this != &other)
        {
            delete[] m_data;

            m_length = other.m_length;
            m_data = new int[m_length];

            std::copy(other.m_data, other.m_data + m_length, m_data);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // Move ctor
    MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other) noexcept
        : m_length(0),
          m_data(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "In MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&&). length = "
                     << other.m_length << ". Moving resource." << std::endl;

        m_data = other.m_data;
        m_length = other.m_length;

        other.m_data = nullptr;
        other.m_length = 0;
    }

    // Move assignment
    MemoryBlock& operator=(MemoryBlock&& other) noexcept
    {
        // Avoid assigning the object to itself
        if (this != &other)
        {
            // Free the existing resource
            delete[] m_data;

            m_data = other.m_data;
            m_length = other.m_length;

            other.m_data = nullptr;
            other.m_length = 0;
        }

        return *this;
    }

private:
    size_t m_length;
    int *m_data;
};
```

What I don't I understand is in the main.
Understand why the move ctor is invoked rather than the copy ctor

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<MemoryBlock> v;

    // In this way the copy ctor is called
    MemoryBlock m(10);
    v.push_back(m);

    // And in this way the move ctor is called, why if std::move is not invoked?
    v.push_back(MemoryBlock(25));

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and built the code and tried to understand, also searching for information in internet without any result

Comment: Because `MemoryBlock(25)` is an rvalue while `m` is an lvalue expression.

Answer (score 1):

`MemoryBlock&&` is an [rvalue reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). So the move constructor:

```
MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock&& other) noexcept
```

Is invoked whenever you pass it an rvalue. There are lots of ways to make an rvalue. `std::move` is only one of those ways. Others, *like in your case*, are creating an unnamed temporary. This can also be done with a function:

```
MemoryBlock foo() { ... }

...

MemoryBlock m{foo()};
```

All of these are rvalues, so the move constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you wrote `v.push_back(m);`, the expression `m` has the value category of **lvalue** and so the lvalue reference version `push_back( const T& )` of `std::vector::push_back` is used which uses **copy initialization**.

On the other hand, when you wrote `v.push_back(MemoryBlock(25));`, the expression `MemoryBlock(25)` is an **rvalue** and so the `push_back( T&& value )` version of `std::vector::push_back` is used. So this version uses the move constructor.

From [std::vector::push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> ```
> void push_back( const T& value );      (1)
> void push_back( T&& value );           (2)
> ```
>
> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1. The new element is initialized as a **copy of value**.
> 2. value is **moved into** the new element.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

- Move constructor is invoked when `rvalues` is used to create a new object
- Copy constructor is invoked when `lvalue` is used to create a new object
- Move assignment operator is invoked when left right-hand-side object is of `rvalues`
- Assignment operator is invoked when left right-hand-side object is of `lvalues`

Coming to your question: *What I don't I understand is in the main. Understand why the move ctor is invoked rather than the copy ctor*

In line `v.push_back(m);`, `m` is an `lvalue` so copy-constructor is called. While in line `v.push_back(MemoryBlock(25));`, `MemoryBlock(25)` is an `rvalue` so move-constructor is called.

Following are some useful reading in this context:

- [std::vector<T,Allocator>::push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)
- [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)
- [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: You wrote twice "so move-constructor is called" in both lvalue and rvalue. Can you explain please

Comment: @Franco See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75599559/12002570)

Comment: @Franco, It was a typo. Corrected it